R send multiple csv's as attachment in one email
I have a little problem with sending multiple csv's as attachment.
In my code I create a folder and subfolder of my dataframe. The filtered dataframe is saved as csv in the folders.
The problem is that it will send(MailR) with the attachments but for every attachment it creates a new email.
I want one email for each recipient with multiple attachments.
In the folders there are more files then the dataframe so it must send only the files from this specific dataframe.
Here is the code:
parent_dir <- "location of the parent_dir path"

df <- data.frame(
  city = c("New York", "Los Angeles", "New York", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Chicago"),
  year = c(2023, 2023, 2023, 2022, 2022, 2022),
  week = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  value = c(100, 200, 150, 300, 250, 400),
  email = c("email1@example.com", "email1@example.com", "email3@example.com", 
        "email4@example.com", "email3@example.com", "email4@example.com")
)

lapply(split(df, list(df$city, df$year, df$week), drop = TRUE), function(sub_df) {
  # Extract unique values
  city <- unique(sub_df$city)
  year <- unique(sub_df$year)
  week <- unique(sub_df$week)

  # Create folder paths
  city_folder <- paste0(parent_dir, city)
  year_folder <- file.path(city_folder, year)

  # Create directories if they don't exist
  if (!dir.exists(city_folder)) dir.create(city_folder)
  if (!dir.exists(year_folder)) dir.create(year_folder)

  # Extract the email address associated with the name
  sub_df$email <- strsplit(sub_df$email, ",") 
  email_list <- unique(unlist(sub_df$email))

  # remove columns uitzendbureau and jaar and email
  remove_year_email <- sub_df %>% 
    select (-c(year, email))

  # Define the file path
  csv_file_path <- file.path(year_folder, paste0(city, " ", week, "-", year, " ", ".csv"))

  # Write the CSV file
  fwrite(remove_year_email, csv_file_path, sep = ";")


  # Send the file via email
  send.mail(
    from = "sender",
    to = email_list,
    subject = "City files",
    body = "test",
    html = TRUE,  
    smtp = list(host.name = "example", port = 1234, 
            user.name = "example",            
            passwd = "example", ssl = TRUE),
    authenticate = TRUE,
    send = TRUE,
    attach.files = csv_file_path,
    debug = TRUE)
})


It doesnt help me with this. list.files doesnt work on "csv_file_path". Is there a other workaround?

Read the accepted solution.  You need to pass a list of paths to individual files, not a path to the folder containing the files.
